# String has an apostrophe, the Javascript breaks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

if `abc="||truth' this ||find"`
I convert `abc` to encode using (`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(abc)`)
I am trying to decode in jquery at server side `'<%=abc %>'`   `('<%=HttpUtility.UrlDecode(FBPages) %>')` 
this is not working e.g `stringText=""`

If I assign this value to variable then I tried two times decode with assign decode value on it then it converts but this is not right way to do 
Waiting for your respose

Comment: Replace ' with &apos; or \' at Server side

Comment: "decode in jquery at server side" doesn't make any sense to me. Can you try to compose one or two coherent code samples that show where this value is coming from, where it's being used, what your expected value is? I just can't parse enough from your narrative to understand what you're doing. E.g. from your first line: `abc="||truth' this ||find"` - where is this happening? In some javascript? In your code behind? somewhere else?#

Answer (score 1):

escape the apostrophe

```
if abc="||truth\' this ||find" I convert abc to encode using (HttpUtility.UrlEncode(abc))
```

Comment: abc="||truth' this ||find" I pass this to encode using (HttpUtility.UrlEncode(abc)) result(%257c%257ctruth%2527%2bthis%2b%257c%257cfind)
I need to decode this